# Conditional Execution of Javascript in a Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

I have some javascript I would like to execute only if a user is logged into my rails app. I set up the user show page as follows:

```
<table class="profile" summary="Profile information">
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
      <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="sidebar round">
      <strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
      <strong>URL</strong> <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %><br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<% if signed_in? %>

<div id="app-body">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World")
</script>
</div>

 <% end %>
```

where signed_in? is a convenience method that returns a boolean if a user is logged in or not. The issue is when I try to load this page I get an error at one line **past** the end of the file:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

Extracted source (around line #48):

```
45: </div>
46: 
47:  <% end %>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? All I find when I search are HAML indentation issues, but here I am using erb, so indentation shouldn't matter.

Comment: as per your code, nothing is wrong. Can you check in your erb file if any block is not ended properly.

Comment: I updated my code to show the entire page, I believe all the blocks are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an extra end in your code after  <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %> remove it.

In ruby no need to have end statement for condition at end of line so <% end %> is not needed for <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>